# Adding DATE and TIME not working when TIME is midnight

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax

I have created a table using the following DAX.

```
Date Selection = 
     ADDCOLUMNS ( 
        CROSSJOIN(
        CALENDAR ( MIN ( 'Date'[Date] ), MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(0,23.5,.5),"Time",TIME([Value],([value]-INT([value]))*60,0))
        ),
        "Visual Date", FORMAT([Date],"dd/mm/yy") + [Time],
        "Order By", FORMAT([Date],"yyyy") & "/" & FORMAT([Date],"MM"),
        "Type", "Half Hourly",
        "Order", 5
)
```

So my issue is when I add my `DATE` and `TIME` column together to create a column called `Visual Date`, everything looks fine but when it reaches to the time `00:00:00` it does not seem to add that time to the corresponding day, it leaves it just as it is.

Is there something that I need to include in order to see `01/01/2021 00:00:00` ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just a visual formatting issue. In the  tab go to the *Format* field and select whatever you want to see.

Comment: The column is set to `Text` but its still not adding the time to that date